# How to count rendered (grand)child components in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a parent component which renders several child components, each of which may or may not render one or more grandchildren. I would like the parent to know how many of those child components rendered, so I can make a nice slider out of them.

My initial attempt is for the parent to have a `registerChildren` callback function,

```
const registerChildren = React.useCallback((count:number) => {
    setCardCount((prevCount) => prevCount + count);
},[])
```

This is passed to the children as a prop; each child would call `React.useEffect(() => props.registerChildren(count),[props, count]);`

But my initial attempt fails, with a "maximum update depth exceeded" message, even though my `registerChildren` function is wrapped in `React.useCallback`.

Dropping "props" from the useEffect dependency array solves the infinite re-render, but Typescript complains about exhaustive dependencies, and it counts the children twice for some reason, so my count is double what it should be. Also, since my actual code involves multiple components, I'd rather not disable the exhaustive-deps on each one.

Here's my best attempt:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dawn-morning-zjt9fs?file=/src/App.tsx:18,13

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the entire `props` object because it's a new object on each render. This causes the `useEffect` to call `props.registerChildren`, update the parent's state and cause the parent and the child to re-render, which creates a new `props` object, and you get a loop.

Destructure `registerChildren` out of `props`:

```
const CardMaker = ({ registerChildren }) => {
```

Pass the function as a dependency, and use it inside `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => registerChildren(count), [registerChildren, count]);
```